# how to build whole python project with cython

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, cython

I have a PySide project with many modules, files and folders. I also used Numpy, Matplotlib and many other modules.

I want to build this project with cython. The code is pure python, and i want cython to add all dependencies together, just like when using `pyinstaller`

is it possible or cython is just made for writing extensions (dll, so, lib) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Cythonize your modules file by file if you want to, however all the dependencies will remain the way they are in Python. Cython does not provide a mechanism to embedd all the required modules the way pyinstaller does.

This is, however, a bad idea. The general approach for optimization in scientific python is that we port to Cython/C/Fortran parts of the code that are computationally expensive, while keeping the rest in pure Python for convenience.

Doing what you propose will be, a) hard to maintain  b) slow, as using Cython is more than about compiling the original Python code, you need to do quite a bit of work to get a significant performance gains, and doing that for all of your code is just a waste of time.

Bottom line, either use Cython only for parts of your code where this will be beneficial and build your project with pyinstaller etc, or switch to C++ or any other compiled language, if that is what you are looking for.